# I want to add background music to my app

Tags: android

I want the user to get the music file from his collection and play it on background of the app. I don't know how to get the path of the music file to use it in my app

Comment: check this out: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

Comment: also try things out for yourself first, then ask here if you run into porblems. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Use services to play back ground music in your app 
[Check out here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)